# Invalid flag but Closed question?

Tags: support, flag-weight

I just flagged [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/310535/how-to-make-juniper-junos-srx210-single-portforward-and-dmz-closed), got invalid flag and some time later the question was closed? I got -10 flag weight to a closed question? Could someone verify?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You flagged for migration to Server Fault or Security.

We have to remember the number one rule in migrations: **Don't migrate crap.**

It was dismissed as invalid on that reason.

It was given a few more seconds to see if it would improve. In that time, it was flagged as NARQ.

It was later closed as not a real question.

Comment: This is not what another admin posted on this post: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2694/what-happens-to-flag-weight-when-2-users-flag-the-same-answer

Comment: Flagged > Dismissed > Flag weight changed > Another flag > Dismissed > Flag weight changed. In the linked, it was Flagged, flagged > Dismissed > Flag weight change. @dio

Comment: What im meaning is: Should I get -10 flag weight loss penalty for flagging a question that anyway got closed? I think at least the -10 penality would be removed...

Comment: You wanted the question be migrated when it failed quality control. Dismissed as invalid. Flag weight drops. Another flag was to close it. Dismissed as valid. If a question is bad or doesn't deserve to live, flag as that. Not to move it somewhere else where it will be closed. @dio

Comment: Sure, now I understand the point. Thank you.